# When are Qt slots called?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

For example, I have a function

```
void A::fun()
{
    do_1();
    emit signal_1();

    do_2();
    emit signal_2();

    do_3();
}
```

There are connections between `signal_1` and `slot_1`; between `signal_2` and `slot_2`. When are the `slot_1` and `slot_2` called? Some answer options:

1. After the fun's return, call `slot_1` before `slot_2`;
2. `slot_1` is called after `do_1` and `slot_2` is called after
   `do_2`

or others.

Comment: #2. Emitting a signal simply means calling all the slots attached to that signal. They are called then and there.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: what if it's a queued connection?

Comment: @Violet Giraffe: even in those cases where you have cross-thread queued connections, `slot_1` is still called after `do_1` and `slot_2` after `do_2`. Exactly how long after, or whether one runs before, after, or in parallel with the other, is unspecified. In any case, the slot invocation is not deliberately delayed until the function returns (as #1 appears to imply), though of course it may happen this way by accident, through the vagaries of multithreading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **Direct connection** ( default when not connecting from different thread )

Slot are called immediately, so result should be:

```
do_1
slot_1
do_2
slot_2
do_3
```

For **Queued connection** called from **the same thread** ( need to set manually )

Execution of function must end, and then main loop can call slots

```
do_1 
do_2 
do_3 
slot_1    
slot_2
```

For **Queued connection** called from **different thread**

It is more complicated because of threading problem. Result can be like in first or second example ( or combination ). **You have no guarantee what calling order it will be!**

```
do_1 
slot_1    
do_2 
do_3 
slot_2
```

Here you can see description of [Qt::ConnectionType](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)

Comment: Yes, direct connection is default.

Comment: Is not direct connection default only for single thread? Queued connection will be default if you are crossing between threads. (so default is "auto")?